# Telugu fonts are not recognized by Blender 2.8

Tags: text-object

Telugu font types with .ttf formatted files are NOT displayed under fonts section of Blender 2.8, Any additional plug-in required or is it an issue?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to select the font for a text object or for the interface in the preferences? Both work for me using this version of the [Dhurjati](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Dhurjati) font.

Comment: I am trying to select the font for a text object, Font Dhurjati is not visible for me in the Blender font window, where the font is already available in the Windows fonts folder.

Comment: Perhaps the actual font file isn't called *Dhurjati.ttf* and therefore doesn't appear after *Curlz* when sorted in alphabetical order?

Comment: No, I checked the properties. It is .ttf file only. I updated the screenshot in the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that your font file is missing the file extension. While Windows knows that it's a TrueType font, Blender simply filters files by their file extension. Since this particular file doesn't have one, it isn't displayed in the file browser. Add the `.ttf` file extension to the file name and it should work properly.

Alternatively you can temporarily disable the file extension filter in Blender and the file will be visible as well.

**Blender 2.80:**

[image: File filter 2.80]

---

**Blender 2.81 and later:**

[image: File filter 2.81]

---

There may be another reason why you don't find your font file in `C:\Windows\Fonts`.
There are two options for installing fonts, you can either *Install* it (only for your user) or *Install for all users*. In the latter case it installs the file as expected into `C:\Windows\Fonts`, however in the former case it will be placed into `C:\Users\[your username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts`.

[image]
<sub>Image source: [Announcing Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 17704](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2018/06/27/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-17704/)</sub>

The Windows Explorer will list all fonts when looking at `C:\Windows\Fonts`, including those that were installed for your user only. Therefore it's necessary to check where the file is actually stored. The easiest way to find the path is by opening the file's properties. With the file selected, right-click on it to open the context menu and select *Properties*. The *General* tab contains the *Location* property, which is the path to the file.

Comment: I disabled the filter, now I could see some files with .ttf files in the explorer except the font I needed.

Comment: Alright. Press WIN + R, type `cmd` and press enter. In the command line window that opens up, type `cd C:\Windows\Fonts` and press enter. Once in the font directory type `dir dhurjati*` and press enter. Does it find the file?

Comment: I think I did the same. If you see the screenshot in the question.

Comment: @djavvadi no it's not the same. The reason why I asked you is because Windows allows you to install fonts for your user only. In that case it will be displayed by the Windows Explorer when navigating to `C:\Windows\Fonts`, however the font file isn't actually stored there. Instead it's actually in `C:\Users\[your username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Fonts`. If you list the files in the command line you would see that the file isn't stored in `C:\Windows\Fonts`. The file location can be identified through its *Properties*.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I realized after my comment earlier. I will configure the fonts folder to the desired location in blender and try again. Thanks a lot for your time and suggestions.

Comment: @djavvadi Great! If my answer solved your question, consider marking it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

first search font in blender, switch to folder windows/fonts, select the font there, and drag and drop in into the blender-folder; it went to fast but the message was something like font installed below 'user/...`' and that's why blender doesn't find it

Comment: This is likely the reason, which is why I've asked them to check the content of the directory from the command line (see comment from Nov 17).

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps for making it work:

1. Go to your Windows Fonts folder:

`(C:\Windows\Fonts)`, and copy all the fonts and then paste them into the `blender-fonts-folder`:
`(C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.0\3.0\datafiles\fonts)`

2. Go to the Blender User Preferences under *Preferences -> File Paths-> Data -> Fonts*

And change the source of the fonts to the `blender-fonts-folder`

You should be able to see all of the fonts now.