# Path to all Font directories on windows 10

Tags: windows

When I installed extra fonts on Windows 10, the OS put the files in my user "AppData ..." location. Now fonts exist in two different directories and I cannot find information on how to setup the font paths so blender sees both directories without having to change the "file Paths" preferences all the time to get to all the fonts on my OS system. Any suggestions?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/158318/74827 You could reinstall the font for all users or bookmark the directory for faster access.