# I downloaded a font from an online website, how do I apply it to my text

Tags: text-object

I downloaded the pistoleer font from this website https://www.wfonts.com/font/pistoleer-3d and i want to apply this font to my 3d text. When I click on the folder next to font and search for the pistoleer font, it is not there. Is there a way I can use this font?

Comment: If it's still text go the the text thing and look through the parts and it should be there.

Comment: Possibly related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/158318/74827

Answer (score 2):

This is a common way to select font from your directory.
[image]
[image]

To get directly to specific directory you store fonts, you can set path in User Preferences.
[image]

If you don't see your font listed, file format of your font is not probably supported, but in your case I can see it (TTF or OTF is OK file format).